# WPF CheckBox not getting checked at initiation (data binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, checkbox

I've just come across this problem with my `CheckBox` data binding. The scenario is:

When I initialize the user interface (start the application), the `CheckBox`es are unchecked, although the property they are bound to is set to true. When I click the `CheckBox`, the property is set to false, but the `CheckBox` is still shown as unchecked. From now on, the data binding works as expected and the `CheckBox` is correctly synched with the binding property.

Here's my XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayTypes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Presentation:TypeDisplayPair}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Display}" Margin="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" />
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And my view model:

```
public class TypeDisplayPair : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool display;
    private readonly Brush color;

    public TypeDisplayPair(string type, bool display)
    {
        Display = display;
        Type = type;
        color = BrushGenerator.GetRandomSolidColorBrush();
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool Display
    {
        get { return display; }
        set
        {
            display = value;
            this.FirePropertyChanged(x => x.Display);
        }
    }

    public Brush Color
    {
        get { return color; }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, as I've spent too much time debugging this and I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided is perfectly correct, you initialization problem probably comes from the way you assign the `DataContext`. I've tried the following:

```
    public Window1()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        DisplayTypes = new ObservableCollection<TypeDisplayPair>()
        {
            new TypeDisplayPair("Alpha", true),
            new TypeDisplayPair("Beta", false)
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

and it works as expected.